# Loading JSON in Place of CSV D3

Tags: javascript, json, csv, d3.js

I'm currently working on a spin-off of d3noob's page here: http://www.d3noob.org/2014/07/d3js-multi-line-graph-with-automatic.html

---

It's almost an identical copy except for two elements. One, I'm trying to load a JSON file instead of D3Noob's preferred CSV. I also want to know if it is easier to use a flat or nested JSON file. If nested would be better, can someone explain or direct me to somewhere that explains nested JSON in d3 a little bit better than what I have been looking for? That'd be great.

---

Just to sum up. 1. How to load JSON in place of a CSV 2. Nested or flat?

---

[Nested Data](http://jsonblob.com/55a6c4bce4b051e806c97d3b)

[Flat Data](http://jsonblob.com/55a6c50fe4b051e806c97d61)

Thank you in advance!

---

Code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<meta charset="utf-8">

<head>
    <style> /* set the CSS */

    body { font: 12px Arial;}

    path { 
        stroke: steelblue;
        stroke-width: 2;
        fill: none;
    }

    .axis path,
    .axis line {
        fill: none;
        stroke: none;
        stroke-width: 1;
        shape-rendering: crispEdges;
    }
    .axis text {
        fill:red;
    }

    .legend {
        font-size: 16px;
        font-weight: bold;
        text-anchor: middle;
    }

    </style>
    <script src="d3.js"></script>

    <script>
    function init(){
        // Set the dimensions of the canvas / graph
        var margin = {top: 30, right: 20, bottom: 70, left: 50},
            width = 600 - margin.left - margin.right,
            height = 300 - margin.top - margin.bottom;

        // Set the ranges
        var x = d3.time.scale().range([0, width]);
        var y = d3.scale.linear().range([height, 0]);

        // Define the axes
        var xAxis = d3.svg.axis().scale(x)
            .orient("bottom").ticks(5);

        var yAxis = d3.svg.axis().scale(y)
            .orient("left").ticks(5);

        // Define the line
        var valline = d3.svg.line()   
            .x(function(d) { return x(d.week); })
            .y(function(d) { return y(d.val); });

        // Adds the svg canvas
        var svg = d3.select("body")
            .append("svg")
                .attr("width", width + margin.left + margin.right)
                .attr("height", height + margin.top + margin.bottom)
            .append("g")
                .attr("transform", 
                      "translate(" + margin.left + "," + margin.top + ")");

        // Get the data
        d3.json("data.01.json", function(error, data) {
            data.chartdata.forEach(function(d) {
                d.week = d.week;
                d.val = +d.val;
            });

            // Scale the range of the data
            x.domain(d3.extent(data.chartdata, function(d) { return d.week; }));
            y.domain([0, d3.max(data.chartdata, function(d) { return d.val; })]);

            // Nest the entries by name
            var dataNest = d3.nest()
                .key(function(d) {return d.name;})
                .entries(data.chartdata);

            var color = d3.scale.category10();   // set the colour scale

            legendSpace = width/dataNest.length; // spacing for the legend

            // Loop through each name / key
            dataNest.forEach(function(d,i) { 

                svg.append("path")
                    .attr("class", "line")
                    .style("stroke", function() { // Add the colours dynamically
                        return d.color = color(d.key); })
                    .attr("id", 'tag'+d.key.replace(/\s+/g, '')) // assign ID
                    .attr("d", valline(d.values));

                // Add the Legend
                svg.append("text")
                    .attr("x", (legendSpace/2)+i*legendSpace)  // space legend
                    .attr("y", height + (margin.bottom/2)+ 5)
                    .attr("class", "legend")    // style the legend
                    .style("fill", function() { // Add the colours dynamically
                        return d.color = color(d.key); })
                    .on("click", function(){
                        // Determine if current line is visible 
                        var active   = d.active ? false : true,
                        newOpacity = active ? 0 : 1; 
                        // Hide or show the elements based on the ID
                        d3.select("#tag"+d.key.replace(/\s+/g, ''))
                            .transition().duration(100) 
                            .style("opacity", newOpacity); 
                        // Upweek whether or not the elements are active
                        d.active = active;
                        })  
                    .text(d.key); 

            });

            // Add the X Axis
            svg.append("g")
                .attr("class", "x axis")
                .attr("transform", "translate(0," + height + ")")
                .call(xAxis);

            // Add the Y Axis
            svg.append("g")
                .attr("class", "y axis")
                .call(yAxis);

        });
    }
    </script>
</head>
<body onload="init()">

<!-- load the d3.js library -->    

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: 1. Use `d3.json` instead of `d3.csv`. 2. Depends on your application. CSV is flat, so chances are that you want to use flat JSON.

Comment: @LarsKotthoff Hm. Something doesn't seem to be working. Did what you said to do, so I'm not quite sure what I did wrong. I could post my code if you like?

Comment: That would help with answering your question, yes.

Comment: @LarsKotthoff There you go. Take a look and tell me what's wrong. Thanks!

Comment: Your code doesn't actually draw a graph. And you haven't defined `chartData`.

Comment: Sorry, I posted the wrong code to start. But I figured it out. I had my code in the head, but was appending the SVG to the body without calling it as an onload function. I got it done and will post the answer sometime today. @LarsKotthoff

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/83471/discussion-between-alexey-ayzin-and-lars-kotthoff).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer is rather simple and I should have realized it earlier. Though I was doing everything correctly, it wasn't working. My problem was that my code was in the head and I was trying to append an SVG to the body without the body existing yet. The only thing I had to do was make all of the head script into a function and call the function when the body loaded, as such.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<meta charset="utf-8">

<head>
    <style> /* set the CSS */

    body { font: 12px Arial;}

    path { 
        stroke: steelblue;
        stroke-width: 2;
        fill: none;
    }

    .axis path,
    .axis line {
        fill: none;
        stroke: none;
        stroke-width: 1;
        shape-rendering: crispEdges;
    }
    .axis text {
        fill:red;
    }

    .legend {
        font-size: 16px;
        font-weight: bold;
        text-anchor: middle;
    }

    </style>
    <script src="d3.js"></script>

    <script>
    function init(){
        // Set the dimensions of the canvas / graph
        var margin = {top: 30, right: 20, bottom: 70, left: 50},
            width = 600 - margin.left - margin.right,
            height = 300 - margin.top - margin.bottom;

        // Set the ranges
        var x = d3.time.scale().range([0, width]);
        var y = d3.scale.linear().range([height, 0]);

        // Define the axes
        var xAxis = d3.svg.axis().scale(x)
            .orient("bottom").ticks(5);

        var yAxis = d3.svg.axis().scale(y)
            .orient("left").ticks(5);

        // Define the line
        var valline = d3.svg.line()   
            .x(function(d) { return x(d.week); })
            .y(function(d) { return y(d.val); });

        // Adds the svg canvas
        var svg = d3.select("body")
            .append("svg")
                .attr("width", width + margin.left + margin.right)
                .attr("height", height + margin.top + margin.bottom)
            .append("g")
                .attr("transform", 
                      "translate(" + margin.left + "," + margin.top + ")");

        // Get the data
        d3.json("data.01.json", function(error, data) {
            data.chartdata.forEach(function(d) {
                d.week = d.week;
                d.val = +d.val;
            });

            // Scale the range of the data
            x.domain(d3.extent(data.chartdata, function(d) { return d.week; }));
            y.domain([0, d3.max(data.chartdata, function(d) { return d.val; })]);

            // Nest the entries by name
            var dataNest = d3.nest()
                .key(function(d) {return d.name;})
                .entries(data.chartdata);

            var color = d3.scale.category10();   // set the colour scale

            legendSpace = width/dataNest.length; // spacing for the legend

            // Loop through each name / key
            dataNest.forEach(function(d,i) { 

                svg.append("path")
                    .attr("class", "line")
                    .style("stroke", function() { // Add the colours dynamically
                        return d.color = color(d.key); })
                    .attr("id", 'tag'+d.key.replace(/\s+/g, '')) // assign ID
                    .attr("d", valline(d.values));

                // Add the Legend
                svg.append("text")
                    .attr("x", (legendSpace/2)+i*legendSpace)  // space legend
                    .attr("y", height + (margin.bottom/2)+ 5)
                    .attr("class", "legend")    // style the legend
                    .style("fill", function() { // Add the colours dynamically
                        return d.color = color(d.key); })
                    .on("click", function(){
                        // Determine if current line is visible 
                        var active   = d.active ? false : true,
                        newOpacity = active ? 0 : 1; 
                        // Hide or show the elements based on the ID
                        d3.select("#tag"+d.key.replace(/\s+/g, ''))
                            .transition().duration(100) 
                            .style("opacity", newOpacity); 
                        // Upweek whether or not the elements are active
                        d.active = active;
                        })  
                    .text(d.key); 

            });

            // Add the X Axis
            svg.append("g")
                .attr("class", "x axis")
                .attr("transform", "translate(0," + height + ")")
                .call(xAxis);

            // Add the Y Axis
            svg.append("g")
                .attr("class", "y axis")
                .call(yAxis);

        });
    }
    </script>
</head>
<body onload="init()">

<!-- load the d3.js library -->    

</body>
</html>
```